# Writing to Multiple Files from Single PCollection (Beam-Python)

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

I am working with multiple file inputs and would like to feed them into a Dataflow pipeline. However, I would like to preserve the outputs to match the number of inputs. Let's pretend we have three different files:

```
 gcs_files = ['gs://bucket/<file1_dir>', 'gs://bucket/<file2_dir>', 'gs://bucket/<file3_dir>']
```

And we want to feed these files into a simple Read->Write pipeline, as follows:

```
 import apache_beam as beam
 from apache_beam.io import ReadAllFromText
 from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
 from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
 
 #Please assume I am using default pipeline options
 print_files = (p | beam.Create(gcs_files) | ReadAllFromText() | WriteToText(<output_path>, shard_name_template = '', file_name_suffix = '.json')
```

The purpose of this pipeline is simple, but I am working on a transforming the format of the input files. Hence, we expect that for every input file there is a corresponding transformed file. The problem with the current setup is that the output is all one file. Is there any way I can preserve the integrity of the original files?

Comment: For your requirement, you can use DoFn object inside [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-sideio) where you can transform multiple files and get output in corresponding files. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Shipra, this is very helpful. If I am understanding this correctly, my transform would need to be an DoFn object and the ParDo would implement the transform on multiple files. What I am curious about now is the upstream and downstream. Can I still use ReadAllFromText() and WriteToText() or do I need to also modify these? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Aaron Gonzalez, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ReadAllFromText(with_filename=True)`, then it gives you key-value pairs of elements where the key is the original filename.
However, then you have to use [WriteToFiles](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/ba647a05dafc16250c52a0630810ec62fca9f0bb/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/fileio.py#L76) to dynamically write to destinations based on the original file name after your transforms to the values.

Or if the size of your gcs_files is small, you can do everything in construction time:

```py
pcolls = {}
for gcs_file in gcs_files:
    pcolls[gcs_file] = (p 
        | f'Create {gcs_file}' >> beam.Create([gcs_file]) 
        | f'Read {gcs_file}' >> ReadAllFromText()
        | f'Your Transform {gcs_file}' >> YourTransform()
        | f'Write {gcs_file}' >> WriteToText())
```

Comment: Know this is a little bit later than your comment, but thanks for your suggestions! I have done both approaches. I feel the first one scales out better. Is there any way to avoid the filename being written to the output file, though? The PCollection includes both filename and records in each row, but ideally we just want to write the transformed records using the filename column to generate the output files.

Answer (score 1):

As for your requirement, you can create a DoFn object that can be passed to [ParDo](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-sideio) which is used for transformation of input PCollection. DoFn contains the processing logic that has to be applied to input collection.ReadAllFromText is used to read from PCollection which can take input as key value pair and WriteToText can be used to shard the output files as given in this [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.io.textio.html).You can refer the code given in this [link](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py).

But if you are performing transformation in groups as for example if you want to get some transformation in Avro format and some in CSV format then you can use [WriteToFiles](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/apache_beam.io.fileio.html).