# Apache Beam: WriteToFiles Based on Filename

Tags: python, apache-beam, dataflow

This question extends the discussion from a previous post:

[Writing to Multiple Files from Single PCollection (Beam-Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72961284/writing-to-multiple-files-from-single-pcollection-beam-python)

In short, I am looking to transform some files but would like for their input and output to match.. so for example:

```
gcs_files: ['input/gcs_file_1.json', 'input/gcs_file_2.json', 'input/gcs_file_3.json']

Output: ['output/gcs_file_1_transformed.json', 'output/gcs_file_2_transformed.json', 'output/gcs_file_2_transformed.json']
```

I am trying `ReadAllFromText(with_filename=True)` and this will yield a tuple in the following format:

```
record = (<gcs_file_dir>, <json_record>)
```

I only need to transform `<json_record>` but I need `<gcs_file_dir>` to make sure I can preserve the same file name as its input.

I know `WriteToFiles()` can use the `destination` argument to assign based on `record[0]`..

I have the following figured out:

```
(p | beam.Create(gcs_files) | ReadAllFromText(with_filename=True) | beam.Map(transform_func) | WriteToFiles(path = <path>, destination = lambda record:record[0))
```

However, I only want to write record[1], since this is the actual transformed value. Is there a way to specify only part of the PCollection for write?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not supported out of the box.

You could write a custom `Sink` (possibly that delegates to a different `FileSink`) that strips off the portion you're not interested in writing to the file.